# Sklearn OneVsRestClassifier - get probabilities for all possibilities of target class

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nlp, svm

I have a pipeline that performs feature engineering and model selection.

*Feature engineering and model selection*

```
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
```

*Pipeline of feature engineering and model*

```
model = Pipeline([('vectorizer', CountVectorizer()),
    ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
    ('clf', OneVsRestClassifier(LinearSVC(class_weight="balanced")))])
```

*Paramater selection*

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
parameters = {'vectorizer__ngram_range': [(1, 1), (1, 2),(2,2)],
               'tfidf__use_idf': (True, False)}

gs_clf_svm = GridSearchCV(model, parameters, n_jobs=-1)
gs_clf_svm = gs_clf_svm.fit(X, y)
print(gs_clf_svm.best_score_)
print(gs_clf_svm.best_params_)
```

*Preparing the final pipeline using the selected parameters*

```
model = Pipeline([('vectorizer', CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,2))),
    ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer(use_idf=True)),
    ('clf', OneVsRestClassifier(LinearSVC(class_weight="balanced")))])
```

*Fit model with training data*
    model.fit(X_train, y_train)

*Save the model*

```
from sklearn.externals import joblib
joblib.dump(model, 'model_question_topic.pkl', compress=1)
```

NOW in another file, I am loading model and predicting

```
from sklearn.externals import joblib
model = joblib.load('model_question_topic.pkl')
```

Now it is predicting the classes properly as class 1

```
question = "apply leave"
model.predict([question])[0]
```

BUT the problem is I need the confidence rate or percentage like

> Class1 = 0.8 -- Class2 = 0.05 -- Class3 = 0.05 -- Class4 = 0.1

```
model.predict_proba([question])[0]
```

How do I do this in python3?

Comment: You are aware that Class2 and Class3 have the same probability in your description? If you really, really want it that way, you calculate which of these thresholds is "closest" to your actual probability. If the result is not unique (like with Class2 and Class3), then use random choice.

Comment: What do you get when you run `model.predict_proba([question])[0]` ?

Comment: `model.predict_proba()` will do the same. Have you tried it?

Comment: model.predict_proba([question])[0] gives as class1

Comment: But i need the confidence rate as this 
Class1 = 0.8 -- Class2 = 0.04 -- Class3 = 0.06 -- Class4 = 0.1
But when i use model.predict_proba() i am getting this error
I tried 
AttributeError: 'LinearSVC' object has no attribute 'predict_proba'

Comment: model.predict_proba() gives error as AttributeError: 'LinearSVC' object has no attribute 'predict_proba'

Comment: Oh yes. I overlooked that part. `LinearSVC` doesnt have `predict_proba()` method, so you cannot do that. You can try using other classifiers (I recommend `LogisticRegression`, it uses the same internal library as `LinearSVC`) for getting the probabilities.